# How to start using yoda speak web service

Tags: javascript, html, xml, web-services, api

I am a web programming beginner
My programming knowledge level cannot handle this problem and I googled a lot but still no result.
I am using yoda speak api
http://www.yodaspeak.co.uk/webservice/yodatalk.php?wsdl

it is an XML file.
XML file is a documentation file?
so how can I set a text box and a button to call the program?
I wrote some codes but probably it does not work.

HTML:

```
<p><h1>Here is a converter for changing your sentences to Yoda's style</h1></p>
<input type="text" id="input">
<button class="button" onclick="convert()">Convert</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function convert(){
    var input = document.getElementById('input').value;

}
```

and sorry I do not know how to continue. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked ws.js. For more info look at

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-wsajax/

You may be better off using REST style API's such as this,

http://funtranslations.com/api/yoda

since integrating with javascript is very easy. Here is a fully functional example using funtranslations yoda API.

```js
 $('#but').click( function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    $.getJSON("//api.funtranslations.com/translate/yoda.json?text=" + input, function( data ) {
       $('#result').append(data.contents.translated);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Here is a converter for changing your sentences to Yoda's style</h1>

<input type="text" id="input" value="Master Obiwan has lost a planet">
<div> Converted Text : <span id="result"></span></div>
<button class="button" id="but">Convert</button>
```